# How to add the Windows Classic Theme to Ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: windows, themes

I would like to add the Windows Classic Theme to Ubuntu 16.04.1.
I have downloaded the theme from this link:
http://b00merang.weebly.com/windows-9x.html
and extracted the files.

What should I do next in order to add the theme (when using Unity Tweak Tool)?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you extract the theme files?

Comment: That site has tutorials for themes - http://b00merang.weebly.com/support--tutorials.html . See also http://b00merang.weebly.com/easy-installation-guide.html. No idea if that theme works with Unity or only gnome shell. Contact the maintainer of the theme if you need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, open the terminal with *ctrl + alt + t* and download the file to your home directory.

```
wget https://github.com/Elbullazul/Redmond-Themes/releases/download/2016%2F11%2F15/Windows.9x.R4.zip
```

Alternatively, move the file you already downloaded to your home directory.

Now unzip the file.

```
unzip Windows.9x.R4.zip
```

Finally move the theme folder to your themes directory.

```
sudo mv Windows\ 9x /usr/share/themes/
```

This should make it visible under the themes section of the settings app

Comment: Is it `Windows\` or `Windows/`? Sorry phone isn't formatting. Forward slash or back slash as you have it?

Comment: Windows backslash